# Check token before accepting multipart in Java

Tags: java, security, servlets, multipart

I have following use case: User uploads files to Java 6 servlet (Apache 6). In order to be able to upload, he must have security token assigned. Is there a way to check this token before accepting whole request with multipart data, and possibly reject? I dont want to use unnecessary bandwith, and defend server against unauthorized access. Of course I have front end validations, but you could still get upload URL from web page and use it for DOS attack, or fill server memory to crash.

Every solution I googled stated you cannot process request before server downloads it. Is there any way to bypass this? Possibly check againts session in some filter? Or maybe I am missing some easiers solution and overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is essentially "How will I handle a request before the request has arrived". Unfortunately that's not possible in our limited universe.

But just because the request has arrived doesn't mean the request is complete. Checking the headers before starting to stream the complete data should be quite enough to prevent any excess bandwidth being used.

So in reality you don't even have a problem.